# Не отправляется почта с сервера Django + nginx + uwsgi

Tags: python, ubuntu, django, nginx, uwsgi

Я отправляю почту через smtp.gmail.com, и дело в том что на локальном рабочем компьютере все нормально, c формы данные уходят и записываются в базу данных и пользователю указавшему свой email отправляется сообщение на указанный адрес.
Все дело так я понимаю в настройке самого сервера nginx и uwsgi. 
Ранее на этом сервере использовался Cherokee Web Server и соответственно сообщения на почту отправлялись в качестве логов при ошибках, и то что почта не оправляется после перехода на nginx + uwsgi я заметил тогда когда разместил новый проект требующий отправки уведомлений на почту пользователям.
Для отправки ранее и сейчас используется почта google, часть настроек из settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'site@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'site@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '123456'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Причем как я писал сообщения с локального сервера для разработчиков с моего рабочего компьютера отправляются и приходят нормально, боевого сервера уже нет.
Лог nginx access.log:

```
xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [13/Oct/2016:20:15:59 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12659 "http://site.com.ua/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.27$3.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"
xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [13/Oct/2016:20:17:05 +0300] "POST /order/ HTTP/1.1" 500 38 "http://site.com.ua/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.$me/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"
```

в error.log ничего не пишет.

На сервере установлена:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
```

nginx имеет такую конфигурацию:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module
```

версия uwsgi:

```
 2.0.13.1
```

конфигурация uwsgi с проекта:

```
[uwsgi]
project = site
base = /home/site

chdir = %(base)/site/%(project)
home = /env/site
module = project.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

pidfile = %(base)/site/%(project)/site.pid

socket = %(base)/site/%(project)/site.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

конфигурация с nginx проекта:

```
server {
    listen          *:80;
    listen          [::]:80;
    server_name     www.site.com.ua;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://site.com.ua$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen          *:80;
    listen          [::]:80;
    server_name     site.com.ua;


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/site/site/site/project;
        access_log off;
        expires 3w;
        # add_header Cache-Control "max-age=1209600";
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/site/site/site/project;
        access_log off;
        expires 12w;
        # add_header Cache-Control "max-age=5258000";
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/site/site/site/site.sock;
    }
}
```

В общей конфигурации /etc/nginx/nginx.conf единственное что я изменял:

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-fon$
```

Также заметил в nginx.conf такую секцию:

```
#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

думаю что в ней проблема и если ее настроить то все решится.
Нашел так же на офф. сайте мануал http://nginx.org/ru/docs/mail/ngx_mail_core_module.html но так настроить отправку почты не получилось.

Выкладываю также отельные части исходников сайта:

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from local_settings import *

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'lgdgl;dgl;keks;lfjjtd;fldgl;;gldgfsfsgldgdlgdlp[gdgdgdgd'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'solo',
    'nested_admin',
    'project',
    'main',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project', 'static')


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project', 'media')


CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '/static/design/js/jquery.2.1.1.min.js'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'forcePasteAsPlainText': True,
    }
}


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'site@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'site@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '123456'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

настройки local_settings.py на сервере:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['site.com.ua', 'www.site.com.ua', 'x.xx.xxx.xxx']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'site',
        'USER': 'site',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

часть представления views.py обрабатывающего URL формы:

```
def order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)            
            email = form.order_email
            if email: 
                name = unicode(form.order_name)
                email = unicode(email)                
                text = name + u', спасибо, мы Вашу заявку получили! Наш менеджер с Вами свяжется в ближаййшее время.'
                msg = EmailMessage(u'Ваша заявка принята', text, u'site@gmail.com', [email])
                msg.content_subtype = "html"            
                msg.send()
            form.save()    
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

сама форма forms.py основанная на модели:

```
from django.forms import *
from .models import Order

class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

Прошу помощи как настроить и разрешить отправку почты на удаленном сервере в связке Django 1.10.2 + nginx 1.4.6 + uwsgi 2.0.13.1.

Если уже у кого-то уже есть опыт или уже примеры рабочих конфигов, т.к. гуглеж толком ничего нормально не принес, все как-то размыто или у меня к сожалению скорей не хватает опыта чтобы понять и самому настроить.

**UPD:** Проверил по рекомендации Elias в консоли, с локального рабочего все нормально отправилось, на удаленном выбросило ошибку авторизации:

```
user@localcomp:~$ ssh root@x.xx.xxx.xxx
(site)root@ssite:/home/site/site/site# cd /home/site/site/site/
(site)root@ssite:/home/site/site/site# source /env/site/bin/activate
(site)root@site:/home/site/site/site# python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> text = 'спасибо, мы Вашу заявку получили! Наш менеджер с Вами свяжется в ближаййшее время.'
>>> msg = EmailMessage(u'Ваша заявка принята', text, 'site@gmail.com', ['site@ukr.net'])
>>> msg.content_subtype = "html"
>>> msg.send()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/env/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 342, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/env/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/env/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 67, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 622, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtN\n5.7.14 V4kwSWno7N6SnUKdMQZ86_3Th2K9Cne4X3e7FN4MQjlmEEaTHwl5Yi3jiT7Vy_DlFjcv2b\n5.7.14 OUh8G4be9qEmbzACnJKgCCWQwtlATsWA4nwbR75upvniJNWo4AMLSyLinB1BuFn8g0a1V2\n5.7.14 G3NUwucq2nJCx2S_9a2NGwj7YhiAeQ7crLfufVJ8vTv9FA8rDV_oAK9BMvmT9S9cqGLRuk\n5.7.14 7O49msgf50imyWx9LXZmRwyPjUutg> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 h36sm4805825ljh.41 - gsmtp')
>>>
```

не могу полностью понять ошибку, почему smtp.gmail.com не авторизирует и не принимает мое исходящее письмо, пожалуйста помогите разобраться.

Comment: порт через который ходит почта открыт?

Comment: В iptables все открыто, добавил правило iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT все равно ошибка, но я еще проверил отправку из консоли на сервере и добавил отчет в свой пост, выдало ошибку авторизации, но до этого с Cherokee Web Server все было нормально, после перехода на nginx и uwsgi уже нет. Я думаю что дело не в портах, т.к. почту не принял сам smtp.gmail.com и выдал ошибку авторизации, почему не понимаю, уже и кодировки адреса менял на koi8-r, все равно не помогло. На локальном рабочем компе все нормально опять же, правда если всего тела поменять кодировку приходит с крякозяблами

Answer (score 1):

Nginx access лог говорит, что во вьюхе ошибка. Возможно проблемы с кодировкой. Нужно узнать подробности. Django использует стандартную библиотеку питона smtplib. Так что вы можете проверить отправку почты в питон консоле или django shell.

```
./manage.py shell
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage             
text = u'спасибо, мы Вашу заявку получили! Наш менеджер с Вами свяжется в ближаййшее время.'
msg = EmailMessage(u'Ваша заявка принята', text, 'site@gmail.com', ['my_best_email@gmail.com'])
msg.content_subtype = "html"            
msg.send()
```

Comment: Спасибо, сделал в консоли как на локальном так и на сервере, в общем на локальном все отлично, а на сервере ошибка авторизации smtp.gmail.com как я понимаю. Я пробовал менять кодировку email адресов на 'koi8-r', если тело сообщения то крокозяблы, но это все не помогло, с локального в любом случае отправляется и приходит с на почту с разными кодировками, с сервера вообще нет. Я выложил в конце своего поста лог ошибки, может получится подсказать и помочь разобраться, почему и что я не так делаю. Может действительно в настройке или моем коде не указано из-за чего на боевом сервере не работает.

Comment: Возможно заблокирован доступ к конкретному серверу. Попробуйте зайти сюда - https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha.

Comment: Спасибо действительно все заработало, но странно, я тоже использовал DisplayUnlockCaptcha и не помогало на старом аккаунте который ранее использовался, и с другим перед этим разрешив доступ к аккаунту ненадежным приложением, в общем настройки были на обоих одинаковые и разлочивал тоже, но не работало. А по прошествии пару дней все заработало, наверное время надо было.

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема решилась сменой smtp.gmail.com на smtp.mail.ru.

Часть настроек с settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'site@mail.ru'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 2525
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "site@mail.ru"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "123456"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

И функция обработки формы из views.py:

```
def order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)        
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)            
            email = form.order_email
            if email:
                email_sender = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
                name = form.order_name
                email = email               
                text = name + ', спасибо, мы Вашу заявку получили! Наш менеджер с Вами свяжется в ближаййшее время.'
                msg = EmailMessage('Заявка на перевозку груза от компании eXimo', text, email_sender, [email])
                msg.content_subtype = "html"            
                msg.send()
            form.save()    
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

Но меня все равно интересует проблема, почему с smtp.gmail.com не отправляется почта, т.к. ранее она отправлялась когда был Cherokee Web Server, но когда месяц ранее тому назад перевел на nginx + uwsgi smtp.gmail.com отказывается пересылать сообщения, с smtp.mail.ru все в порядке. На локальном рабочем комп'ютере с Django 1.10.2 работающем в режиме отладки все нормально отправляется через оба smtp сервера.

Удаленный VPS сервер работает на FastVPS, google почтовый аккаунт ведет рассылку тоже с другого сервера на котором стоит Cherokee Web Server и все и отправляются отчеты с ошибками на почту нормально, и я не думаю что это бан от google, т.к. этот аккаунт на нескольких серверах и мне на почту до сих пор идут отчеты с ошибками с них.
Еще раз выкладываю отчет ошибки с консоли, может быть кто-нибудь знает решение данной проблемы:

```
user@localcomp:~$ ssh root@x.xx.xxx.xxx
(site)root@ssite:/home/site/site/site# cd /home/site/site/site/
(site)root@ssite:/home/site/site/site# source /env/site/bin/activate
(site)root@site:/home/site/site/site# python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> text = 'спасибо, мы Вашу заявку получили! Наш менеджер с Вами свяжется в ближаййшее время.'
>>> msg = EmailMessage(u'Ваша заявка принята', text, 'site@gmail.com', ['site@ukr.net'])
>>> msg.content_subtype = "html"
>>> msg.send()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/env/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 342, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/env/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/env/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 67, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 622, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtN\n5.7.14 V4kwSWno7N6SnUKdMQZ86_3Th2K9Cne4X3e7FN4MQjlmEEaTHwl5Yi3jiT7Vy_DlFjcv2b\n5.7.14 OUh8G4be9qEmbzACnJKgCCWQwtlATsWA4nwbR75upvniJNWo4AMLSyLinB1BuFn8g0a1V2\n5.7.14 G3NUwucq2nJCx2S_9a2NGwj7YhiAeQ7crLfufVJ8vTv9FA8rDV_oAK9BMvmT9S9cqGLRuk\n5.7.14 7O49msgf50imyWx9LXZmRwyPjUutg> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 h36sm4805825ljh.41 - gsmtp')
>>>
```

Буду очень признателен за любую помощь, т.к. хотелось бы все-таки использовать smtp.gmail.com чем от mail.ru